# How can I make a batch file calling JBOSS to run like a service?

Tags: jboss, service, batch-file

Just curious if theres a way to do this...

Basically I'll be calling Jboss from a batch file, and I want to have it run in a seperate thread or service

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [jbosssvc.exe](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossNativeWindows) to run jboss as a service.

Once you have that set up, you can put in your batch file `net start JBAS4SVC`